# Choosing Contactors for an EV Battery Pack

Tags: batteries, bms, contactor, electric-vehicle

I’m designing a battery pack and am uncertain about which contactor to select. Many electric vehicles (EVs) use three contactors: one each in the positive terminal, negative terminal, and precharge circuits. I believe we can use one type of contactor for all three positions.

[image: simple diagram]

The current rating of the contactor should match the rated current of the pack. Let's assume we have 3 modules, each with a 6s20p configuration and our pack voltage is 400V. The "Max. Discharge Current" for each cell is 10,000 mA for continuous discharge and 15,000 mA for non-continuous discharge. My question is: which value should we use to calculate the rated current for the contactor?

If we use "Max. Discharge Current for continuous discharge" of 10,000 mA for our calculation, then we would have 10 A * 20 = 200 A. Does this imply that our contactor should have a rated current of 200 A?

I've noticed a few Tesla models using the Gigavac 200, which is rated for 500+ Amps at 12-800 Vdc. Why is it specified as 500+ and not an exact number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which value should we use to calculate the rated current for the contactor?

> Does this imply that our contactor should have a rated current of 200 A?

You need to ensure that your contactor will survive whatever current might cross it (including worst case scenario).

If you have a fuse or another overcurrent between the batteries and the contactor, then you need to choose a contactor that supports whatever current can pass through your overcurrent protection, including :

- high currents for short duration (a thermal fuse for example won't blow on a short high current pulse)
- somewhat lower currents for somewhat longer durations (most fuses allow several time the nominal current for a few seconds)
- a bit more than the blowing current of the fuse for unlimited duration (nb : most fuses don't blow at there nominal current, but need some higher current before really flowing)

> I've noticed a few Tesla models using the Gigavac 200, which is rated for 500+ Amps at 12-800 Vdc. Why is it specified as 500+ and not an exact number?

If you look at the datasheet of the [Gigavac 200](https://www.sensata.com/sites/default/files/a/sensata-gigavac-gv200-series-open-contactors-datasheet.pdf), you have this very interesting figure :
[image]
You can sustain 500A for about 600 seconds (ie 10 minutes).

The current you can sustain for infinite time seems more like 300A.

On the other hand, an inrush current of 2000A is OK for 20 seconds.

So there is no hard limit for the maximum peak current (or at least I didn't found it by quickly reading through the datasheet). The maximum current depends mainly on how long you want to sustain it (and how well you can cool down the contactor).

So the 500+ A is just a marketing value for a typical use case (for a car, if you can be full power for 10 minutes, it's more than sufficient, usually you only accelerate strongly for a few tens of seconds).

So to answer your main question about choosing your contactor : what matters is not the current rating of your battery itself, but of the current protection that is (hopefully) either included in the battery or put at its output. Your switch must be rated to support all (current, duration) pairs your current limiting circuit can let through.

So find the curve current-vs-duration of your battery protection, and compare it with the one of your contactor. Take the worst case scenario for both (ie highest (current,time) for the protection, and lowest resistance for the contactor. If the curve for the contactor is above the one for the protection with decent margin, you are fine. If not, choose another contactor.

NB : a single figure for maximum current will not suffice to know if you are fine or not

Comment: Thanks, Sandro for the interpretation of the Time Current Characteristic (TCC) figure. Based on the given info, maximum discharge durations may depend on many factors such as loads (FLA) and temperature. Everything seems clear now.